# JavaScript to switch between multiple macros in iMacros add-on for Firefox

Tags: javascript, macros, imacros

I'm using iMacros add-on on Firefox, and I'm trying to make a JavaScript so it switches between multiple macros in same web page and the condition must be 
if the tag is not available in the page, move to the next macro and so on.

Comment: Please clarify the question. What have you tried?

Comment: i didn't try JavaScript yet , i have no idea how to do that so i switch between macros manually

Comment: i have 4 macros each macro related to 1 tag
if the tag not available then it must move to the mext macro 
i will play this in loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play the following js-script on this page. I hope that you’ll understand the idea.

```
if (iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"JavaScript to switch between multiple macros in imacros add-on for Firefox" CONTENT=EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND') == 1) {
    iimPlay('CODE: PROMPT "Not found the title!"');
} else {
    iimPlay('CODE: PROMPT "Found the title!"');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shugar for helping out. I like to help the new ones who are little vague. Its hard for them to pick up stackoverflow style right away.

Comment: @Noitidart, absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

here what I've tried so far is:

```
var i, retcode;
var report;
var macrolist = new Array();


if (iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"some text" CONTENT=EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND') == 1) {
macrolist.push("secondmacro.iim");
}
else 
{
macrolist.push("firstmacro.iim");
}
```

This would be perfect for two macros referring to the same text, lets say I have four macros and each macro needs to find an unique text to go on.

So how can I make it check if another text is available for second macro and so on

Comment: You may just add another ‘if’-clause for the second (and further) macros, i.e.: `if (iimPlayCode('...') == 1) { if (iimPlayCode('...') != 1 { macrolist.push("secondmacro.iim"); } else ... } else ...` Alternatively, in case of many options, one can extract the necessary text and use a ‘switch’-clause. It’s for you to choose.

Comment: i checked [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) , the  ‘switch’-clause seems better can you give me an exemple of how to use it in such situation , thanks in advance

Comment: Describe your situation in more detail.

Comment: In my page there is 4 `DIV` tags they appear and disappear randomly.
The script should check at first the `TXT` of each `DIV`, if available so it launch a specific macro for it , and they should be done all in raw , thats why i felt that the ‘switch’-clause will work better in this case

Comment: If you have 4 different ‘DIV’ tags, write the code (or function) that returns, for example, the available tag number (1-4). Further add the block `switch (number) { case 1: macrolist.push("firstmacro.iim"); break; case 2: macrolist.push("secondmacro.iim"); break; … }`